# Eclipse Plugin: Adding handlers programmatically vs. added via extension framework

Tags: eclipse-plugin, handler

I have in my Eclipse plugin some programmatically defined handlers (for instance cut/copy/paste) and some other editor related actions that are defined via the extension framework.
If I close the view of my plugin and reopen it the handlers defined via extension framework seems to break and when executed seems to use disposed gui elements. The programmatically one are readded in the createViewPart() Method and keep working.

I don't get how to reload the handlers defined via extension framework?

Comment: I have never had problems like this, I would say there is no need of "reloading" handlers, code and/or stack trace might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In handlers added through the extension framework, they are expected to get what then need to operate from the `ExecutionEvent` that's provided in the `execute(*)` method.  `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil` can extract most of the workbench related information for you.

Saving state in your handler between calls is not guaranteed to work, as the framework can dispose and recreate the handler as it needs to.